# Choosing thermal printer for Android

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers

What is the most compatible, easy to interface label printer for android.
I have been looking through Zebra, Star, Epson and Brother. Zebra SDK is an exe, which I am not able to explore in my mac. Epson mostly support thermal receipt printer, but I need label printer.

To help my research, if I have the option to choose a printer, which one should I consider which has the best support (for development) for Android.I could interface through USB or Wifi/Bluetooth.

Comment: The Android SDK for Zebra printers work on mac too. Just install the SDK on a windows machine and copy the library jar over to your mac. (You can grab the javadoc too if you'd like)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the Zebra printers with success.  They have an SDK for printing to the device that manages some of the finer points for connection via bluetooth.  Whilst I've tried many other printers on Windows, the Zebra is the only one I've tried on Android and it seemed to work fine for our project.

Comment: It was the MZ320 using CPCL language.